# Resolution issues while exporting for DRIBBBLE

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resolution, dimensions, dribbble

I am new to Dribbble and it's really cool place for designers but i'm facing problem in resolution and dimensions for Dribbble shots.

I've a habit of exporting vector work at 300ppi jpg/png.

As per Dribbble guidelines I created an artboard of 400*300px and exported it to 300 ppi and my output file does not turn out be 400*300px but something quite larger (1668*1251).
I researched about it a lot I found (click here for answer [1](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8955733#8955733)).

According to it the only way to get exact dimensions is exporting my file at 400*300 @ 72ppi.
At 72ppi my work doesn't look neat and it looks horribly pixelated.

If you're a Dribbble user, what dimensions and resolution you export your work?

I am using Adobe illustrator CC 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Here's why your image is outputting at a different size.

400px ÷ 72ppi = 5.5556"

300px ÷ 72ppi = 4.1667"

5.5556" x 300ppi = 1667px

4.1667" x 300ppi = 1250px

Basically by telling Illustrator to output at 300ppi it's increasing the image size in pixels, so that it will still print at 5.5556" x 4.1667"

If you aren't printing the work, and it's for the web, there is no need to output at 300ppi. Just leave it at the default 72ppi. Web browsers ignore the PPI setting anyway, and therefore the PPI setting is irrelevant for the web.

However, just so you know, a 400px x 300px image is a small low resolution image.  If you zoom in on it, you will see pixels!  View the image without any zoom, in a browser as intended, and it will look fine.

Here is a 400px x 300px image at 72ppi. There is no pixelization

[image]